# Testing for success (no revert) in Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, mocha, chai

I'm using hardhat with mocha and chai to write tests for a contract. I'm trying to write a test that will expect a function call to be successful (not to revert); the function does not emit any events.

Some combinations I expected to work but did not are: `not.to.be.reverted`, `not.to.be.rejected`, `to.be.ok`, `to.be.fulfilled`.

What is the recommended way to test for success?

Comment: Did you try .to.not.be.reverted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it:

```
.to.not.be.reverted
```

It raises and error if the transaction reverted, and even returns the reason why:

```
  1) Access Control Test
   Setup organization
     Call functions that use AccessControl from uncertified Account:
 AssertionError: Expected transaction NOT to be reverted, but it was reverted with "VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'AccessControl: account 0x15d34aaf54267db7d7c367839aaf71a00a2c6a65 is missing role 0xd3879079fee113afaf053f6103cde29a976de27944824d68ae5bbbdb9b498e49'"
```